# pywinauto not connecting to After Effects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywinauto, after-effects

```
from pywinauto import application
app = application.Application().connect(process=7996)
app.print_control_identifiers()
```

Why does this code not work? it produces the error.

```
AttributeError: Neither GUI element (wrapper) nor wrapper method 'print_control_identifiers' were found (typo?)
```

The only reason i can think of is that it's because its a 64 bit application and i have 32 bit Python.

Answer (score 0):

`connect()` worked fine in your code. Next line: `print_control_identifiers()` is not a method of `app` object. You need to create top level window specification for that:

```
app.TopWindowTitle.print_control_identifiers()
```

To list top window titles:

```
print([w.window_text() for w in app.windows()])
```